# Is this quote by Francisco d'Anconia a veiled reference to the Strike?

Tags: ayn-rand, atlas-shrugged

Early on in the book, Francisco d'Antonia comments,

> “In his lifetime, every one of my ancestors raised the production of d’Anconia Copper by about ten per cent. I intend to raise it by one hundred.”

He later comments after the Strike that, unlike his ancestors, all of the fortune was his - without the interference of the Looters who tried to claim it. Is this quote a veiled reference to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think so. That statement was made by Francisco before the Strike had commenced, and I believe simply highlights Francisco's ambition and drive.